# Undo when user edits more than one cell at a time

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to prevent people from editing multiple cells at the same time (e.g, selecting a range and then deleting, or pasting values from outside excel to a range, etc)

I tried this but it seems to loop forever because apparently `Application.Undo` triggers a `Worksheet_Change` event.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then
        Application.Undo
        MsgBox "Error"
    End If
End Sub
```

I want my users to edit the worksheet one cell at a time. I'm open to any suggestions.

Comment: `application.enableevents = False` at the start and re-enable at the end.

Comment: @Warcupine Precisely what was needed!!

Comment: In the (unlikely but you never know) event someone clears the whole sheet, `Target.Cells.Count` will overflow, so maybe switch that out to `Target.Cells.CountLarge`

Comment: @TimWilliams Not unlikely at all. lol. Thanks!